# PDE equation conversion to parabolic PDE problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, transformation

Hello guys I am new here and I accept a  serious problem with my exercising. Pronunciation says that I have to transform the dependent variable of this equation $\frac{\partial V}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial x^2}+\left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}\right)^2$ reduce this equation into a parabolic differential equation problem and solve it numerically.
The problem is that i can't find the the conversion.
$V$ :dependent variable
Can anyone help me because i am really in a difficult situation.

Comment: Well come to MATHEMATICS. Please explain your works so we can help you better.